# Stuck with python code for the following question

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write python code(2.7 version) for the following and also explain the logic because i am not understanding please explain.

Eight houses ,represented as cells , are arranged in a straight line.Each day every cell competes with its adjacent cells(neighbours). An integer value of 1 represents an active cell and a value of 0 represents an inactive cell.If the neighbours on both the sides of a cell are either active or inactive,the cell becomes inactive on the next day; otherwise the cell becomes active.The two cells on each end have a single adjacent cell ,so assume that the unoccupied space on the opposite side is an inactive cell.Even after updating the cell state , consider its previous state when updating the state of other cells. The state information of all cells should be updated simultaneously.

Write an algorithm to output the state of the cells after the given number of days.

==================================================

Input

The input to the function/method consists of two arguments:

states , a list of integers representing the current state of cells ;

days ; an integer representing the number of days.

Output

Return a list of integers representing the state of the cells after the given number of days.

Note

The elements of the list states contains 0s and 1s only.

```
TESTCASES 1:
INPUT:
[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],1
EXPECTED RETURN VALUE:
[0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0]

TESTCASE 2:
INPUT:
[1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,],2
EXPECTED RETURN VALUE:
[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]
```

==================================================================

```
def cellCompete(states,days):

    #write your code logic with explanation

    pass
```

==================================================================

I tried with following code but its giving the wrong output:

```
def cellCompete(c,d):
     for _ in range(d):
          for i in range(8):
                n=c[i]
                if i>0 and i<7:
                    c[i]=0 if c[i+1]==a else 1
                elif i==0:
                                    c[i]=0 if c[i+1]==0 else 1
                            else:
                                      c[i]=0 if a==0 else 1
                    a=n
          return c;
```

Comment: Please format your code with code blocks, and instead of adding answers, edit your original post.

Comment: Sounds like a one dimensional version of Conway’s Game of Life. The usual way of solving is to create a new output list and compute its contents based on the input list.

Comment: Can you please write the exact piece of code because i tried a lot and it dint work out for me.

Comment: I’m not sure from your question what the exact rules are for when a cell changes state.

Comment: Can you please Like the Question and spread . lets see if anyone else can answer.

Comment: If the neighbours on both the sides of a cell are either active or inactive,the cell becomes inactive on the next day; otherwise the cell becomes active.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the indexing of lists where `lis[-1]` wraps around to access the last element.

This function adds an extra inactive cell at the end to make the checking of adjacent cells at the ends of the lists work out.

```
def cellCompete(c, d):
    c = c[:]
    for _ in range(d):
        q = [0] * len(c)
        c.append(0)
        for index in range(len(q)):
            next_state = 0 if c[index - 1] == c[index + 1] else 1
            q[index] = next_state

        c = q
    return c
```

Output as both test cases.

Comment: Yeah very much thankful to you. Output is correct . Can you please explain the logic of the code as well .

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? Any specific questions you have can be made into new questions on this site.